# Why would Apache serve CakePHP .ctp files as HTML?

Tags: apache, cakephp

I moved a site that was working 100% on II6 to a local WAMP installation, apache 2.2. Both are using PHP 5.2 and the same version of cake (the same exact set of files from the base www directory). When I try to load my '/' page (which redirects to a login page) I get this:

```
charset();?> css('riverstone');?>
renderElement('layout/header_menu');?> renderElement('layout/header_logo');?>
check('Message.flash')) $session->flash(); print $content_for_layout; ?>
renderElement('sub_menu/'.$submenu, array('vars'=>$this->viewVars)):'';?>
```

The code generating the page is this (snip from default.ctp).

```
    <?=$html->charset();?>
    <link rel="icon" href="<?=$this->webroot;?>favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?=$this->webroot;?>favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <?=$html->css('riverstone');?>
    </head>
<body class="<?=!$submenu?'wide':''?>">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <?=$this->renderElement('layout/header_menu');?>
            <img src="/img/ajax.gif" alt="Loading" style="position:absolute;top:32px;padding-left:5px;display:none;" id="ajax_icon"/>
            <?=$this->renderElement('layout/header_logo');?>
            <h2><?=isset($mainpage) ? $mainpage : $title_for_layout;?></h2>
            <h3><?=$subpage;?></h3>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="content-main">
            <script src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.minpacked.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
            <?
            if ($session->check('Message.flash')) $session->flash();
            print $content_for_layout;
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="sub-menu"><ul><?=!empty($submenu)?$this->renderElement('sub_menu/'.$submenu, array('vars'=>$this->viewVars)):'';?></ul></div>
```

If you view the source of the page it's just the raw text from the .ctp file and it's reading the

Resources I found said Apache shouldn't even be able to "see" the ctp files, it should all be handled by cake, but no extra configuration is suggested anywhere; my rewrites are working fine (the cake test page worked before I moved the actual site). I tried setting the document root in Apache to /www and also to /www/app/webroot but both have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to enable php short tag on the server.

Comment: or stop using short tags, and eliminate this problem altogether on any server!

Comment: Thank you! Completely passed my mind as I've never used short tags, never even saw them used until I inherited this project.